# Error while compiling a C++ project with devenv using Coverity. (cov-build.exe)

Tags: msbuild, devenv, coverity-prevent, coverity

When running a Coverity build I get the following error:

```
Failed to locate msbuild.exe when handling devenv template configuration. Shutting down resident msbuild processes is impossible.
```

Can't find it in Google!

Does anyone know what this might mean?
How do I investigate this?

When I build from command line without Coverity it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you start `cov-build devenv` one of the things it tries to do is kill off idle msbuild.exe processes because if they are not killed, devenv will pass the build directive to msbuild without cov-build being able to see it (and that's how it knows how to build your files).

There are a few ways you can resolve this - it depends on how you are invoking cov-build, how your compiler configuration is set up, etc.   For example, you could call `cov-build msbuild` directly rather than going through `devenv`.

I would recommend opening a support case with Coverity (since you have support if you have a license for it).  E-mail them at support@coverity.com and I'm sure they can suggest additional debugging steps.